# Computer will not boot bios or POST

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

**Problem**

Computer powers on, fans turn, rgb lights up, but computer will not POST, boot bios, BEEP, or display anything on monitor.

**Back History**

- Was playing Warzone and computer rebooted randomly.
- Powered back on once and loaded warzone again. But computer shut down.
- No longer able to get Display, POST, or BEEPs

**Things I've already tried**

1. Took out graphics card and ran HDMI and DP cables directly to
   integrated ports on the I/O shield.
2. Reset CMOS
3. Unplugged all components and basically inspected motherboard. No visible
   damage anywhere. Rebuilt PC, still no nuts. Reset CMOS again, still no
   luck.
4. Swapped ram out, see details below
5. Replaced CMOS battery (I know, most likely not going to do anything, but
   worth a try)

**Details**

- Motherboard - MSI z390 carbon
- Processor - Intel I9 9900k
- Ram - 32 gb Corsair or 16 gb Corsair w/rgb
- GPU - Asus RTX 2080 ROG
- PSU - Seasoning 850w

**My Theory**

I think either the motherboard is bad or the processor is bad. But I want to know how to test it to be sure before I drop any coin on it.

Comment: Test? You'll need alternate hardware to test on both ends to be sure. A computer hardware shop will often have such alternate hardware and may be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might do this as a next step.